# How do i get sqlite to preserve string-type when it contains numbers only?

Tags: sqlite, nativescript

When i create a table with a STRING field with the nativescript-sqlite plugin, and enter a string "000123" (any string containing numbers only), and later fe3tch the record from the DB, it returns an int (123) and does not persist the string type. Is there any trick for this ?  I enclose the code i use for creating, saving and returning the field....

creating the table  ( the code has been abreviated )

```
 var Name = 'users';
 var TableDef = MedID INT, Naam STRING ,Pin STRING';
 db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + Name + 
 "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY         AUTOINCREMENT," + TableDef + " )")
 .then(result =>  {...} );
```

Inserting a record

```
db.execSQL( "INSERT INTO users (MedID,Naam,Pin) VALUES (?, ?,?)",
 [1,'John Doe','000123'] )
 .then(id => {...} );
```

returning the pincode

```
var db_name = "scanapp.db";
new sqlite(db_name).then(db => 
{    
     db.all('select MedID, Naam, Pin from users order by ID ')
    .then (rows => { console.log (rows[0][2]); });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your table definition. Your `Pin` column was given a type of `STRING`.

In Sqlite, a column type is used to set the *affinity* of that column and control the preferred way to store values in that column. If you look at [the rules for determining affinity type based on column type](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html#determination_of_column_affinity), you'll see that the type `STRING` defaults to the `NUMERIC` affinity, which means:

> A column with NUMERIC affinity may contain values using all five storage classes. When text data is inserted into a NUMERIC column, the storage class of the text is converted to INTEGER or REAL (in order of preference) if such conversion is lossless and reversible.

The interesting thing here is the *lossless and reversible* bit, because this clearly isn't thanks to the leading 0's being stripped. I suspect that's a bug.

Anyways, the fix is to change your table definition to use types that have `TEXT` affinity - like `TEXT`, `CHAR`, etc, instead of the current `STRING`:

```sql
sqlite> create table foo(bar text, baz string);
sqlite> insert into foo values ('0012', '0012');
sqlite> select bar, typeof(bar), baz, typeof(baz) from foo;
bar         typeof(bar)  baz         typeof(baz)
----------  -----------  ----------  -----------
0012        text         12          integer
```

Comment: Apparently everyone on the sqlite mailing list has a different definition for "lossless and reversible" than I do.

Comment: And now the documentation has been updated to reflect the actual behavior. Much better now.

Answer (score 0):

Does the INSERT command execute without throwing any exceptions? I'm asking because you are explicitly inserting the MedID which is the table's primary AUTOINCREMENT field.

Your INSERT statement should be like:

```
db.execSQL("insert into users (Naam, Pin) values (?, ?)", ["John Doe", "000123"], function(err, id) {
  console.log("The new record id is:", id);
});
```

Always check the **err** to make sure whether your command is successfully executed or not.

```
if (err) {
      console.error("Failed to insert!", err);
    } else {
      console.log("The new record id is:", id);
    }
```

Please check the [NativeScript sqlite documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-sqlite) for much more useful info.

Good luck.